# Getting access to a wide range of test PCs

Tags: testing

Are there any companies/services which will let you get remote access to *specific* hardware? Developing games, you need to test on a who battery of hardware combinations - CPU/GPU/OS/etc and for a small company that's pretty impracticable.
So say I want to test on a Core 2 Duo + nVidia 8400GS... or even on a certain model like a Dell Vostro 1234... do companies sell remote access to allow outsourcing the hardware in this way?

*If this is better on another site, please say in a comment rather than just close-vote! Where* does *software testing belong on SE anyway?*

Comment: More a job for ServerFault, since this is really more of a question about hosting. The testing aspect isn't really relevant.

Comment: Is it hosting though per se... I wouldn't expect to see these services advertised as hosting but "outsourced test environments" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a variety of systems, why not release a public beta? I can think of no better way to run the software on a wide range of hardware configurations.

Comment: Because it's not for public use, it's a bespoke application for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Our company is using [Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) to address a similar problem.

Comment: It doesn't quite seem similar when all their instances are virtualized.

Comment: That makes sense . . . our application is not nearly as hardware-dependent as a game would be.  I just thought I'd throw this out there.  Hopefully someone will have an answer that is more useful for your purposes.